# On which framework h2o automl is build?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, automl

AutoKeras is built on Keras framework and Google automl is built on tensorflow. So on which framework does the h2o build ? or is it made from scratch ?

Comment: On H2O http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html

Comment: @Karl So they have made it from scratch ??

Comment: @Rutvik Yes, the H2O algos are written from scratch to be distributed/parallelized and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2O's AutoML (first released in 2017) is built on the Open Source [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) distributed machine learning stack. It's built on Java but it has Python and R bindings, so you can use those languages.